# Sharepoint content are not searchable...why?

Tags: search, sharepoint

I create a form form infopath. On that form I took the text boxes with corresponding fields, then I embed the form in SharePoint. Then in my document library, clicked "new", filled up data. Then I can see the data columns wise in my document library. Let's say I fill data as "Lalit" when I tried to search it, it gave me message:

> "No results matching your search were found."
>   1.Check your spelling. Are the words in your query spelled correctly?
>   2.Try using synonyms. Maybe what you're looking for uses slightly different words.
>   3.Make your search more general. Try more general terms in place of specific ones.
>   4.Try your search in a different scope. Different scopes can have different results.

What should the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SharePoint Server you have to configure the search before you can use it. SharePoint then crawls the content of you site and builds an index for it, that will be used by the search.

You find the search configuration in the Central Administration under the [Shared Service Provider](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303421.aspx) for you web application.